# Execute a function with an instance based on user input (in conjunction with a class) [Python]

Tags: python, function, class, instance

While I was working on a little project I hit a bit of a snag. I want to execute a function with certain instance of a class but the user needs to input them. I know you can just input the instance in the code itself like:

`run(instance1,instance2)`

A small example in psuedo code. ( I know the code is pointless its just to illustrate the point.)

```
class main()
    def __init__(self, a, b ,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

test1 = main(10, 443, 5, 46)
test2 = main(340, 3, 554, 2134)
test3 = main(140, 3, 98, 6)
test4 = main(0, 345, 7, 46)

def check(instance_a, insance_b):
    print instance_a.b, instance_b.c

def run(instance_a, instance_b):
    while True:
       check(instance_a, instance_b)

instance_a = raw_input('set instance a')
instance_b = raw_input('set instance b')

run(instance_a, instance_b)
```

The idea is that the user can input test1,test2,test3,test4 and the programm would then execute  all of the functions with the 2 isntances chosen. Is this at all possible? Or do you have to manually make all the options with if statements? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm still not clear what you want to do.  I think I am getting hung up on the fact that you have an infinite loop with only a print statement in it.

Comment: As I said its exaple code I just wanted to know how to run a function with user defined instanses. The loop is just there as an example of switching instances between functions. I hope this has cleared up your confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, store the instances in a dictionary by name, rather than as separate variable names:

```
tests = {'test1': main(...), 'test2': main(...), ...}
```

Then you can easily access them based on the user input:

```
instance_a = raw_input('set instance a')
instance_b = raw_input('set instance b')
run(tests[instance_a], tests[instance_b])
```

and add some simple checking for valid input:

```
if instance_a not in tests:
    # complain to user
```